# How i can match root of domain name without www. using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I try to match root of domain name with regular expressions in JS. I have a problem when path hasn't **www.** in himself.

For example, i tried match from this string:

```
(http://web.archive.org/web/20080620033027/http://www.mrvc.indianrail.gov.in/overview.htm)
```

Thats regex what i try is presented below. I try him on [regex101.com](http://regex101.com)

```
/(?<=(\/\/(www\.)|\/\/)).+?(?=\/)/g
```

I expect the output array with names `web.archive.org` and `mrvc.indianrail.gov.in` but get `web.archive.org` and `www.mrvc.indianrail.gov.in` with **www.** in second case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this regex:

```
(?<=https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)(?!www\.).+?(?=\/)
```

it matches `web.archive.org` and `mrvc.indianrail.gov.in` without the `www.`

**demo:** https://regex101.com/r/5ZqK7n/3/

Differences with your initial regex:

- In your positive lookbehind clause, I have `s?` to support `https:` URLs (remove it if not necessary)
- `(?:www\.)?` can appear 0 to 1 time
- After the lookbehind you add a negative lookahead `(?!www\.)` to not match, to avoid that your `.+?` matches the initial `www.`

Comment: can you help with this again? i try parse html string for domain names, but don't know how end with this, it's almost done. In link below you can see that matches from 30 to 33 is incorrect.
https://regex101.com/r/rkaAay/1

Comment: @VsevolodFedorov: ok got you! Following this doc: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hostname.7.html you see the convention for the characters in the hostnames, you will therefore have to replace the `.` by a char class `[\w.-]` as it would accept too many characters including spaces...

Comment: no, i mean i need to match a string with dot, because input string has string concatenation and this regex match **sb** and **b** from `"https://sb" : "http://b") + ".scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js";`

Answer (score 0):

First you have to understand how regex matches.

If you set or(|) group, it matches whole group for each one character.
For example, input is `123 122` and pattern is `(123|12)`.
Second group(12) always matches to both of two words.

Because first and second character of both two words matches `12` group already at second character, there is no need to check third character.

I think your purpose is to apply `123` group first for whole word(123) and ignore `12` group because `123` group already matched.

I suggest not using look behind, and get first group($1) like following:

`\/\/(?:www\.)?(.+?)\/`

https://regex101.com/r/Ufxzeq/1